# Javascript - Replace multiple elements in an array using index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider following array in Javascript:

```
var array1 = ['S', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'O', 'W'];
```

Now I want to replace all the elements at once from index 3 to 9 in following way:

```
array1 = ['S', 'T', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'L', 'O', 'W'];
```

Is it possible to achieve in javascript ?

**Note**: I want to perform following operation using array only

Comment: `array1.forEach((a,b,c)=>array1[b]=(b<9 && b>2)?'X':a);`

Comment: @dandavis your boundaries are off, 9 is inclusive

Comment: touchè. it's late here, but the main point is closure-ing the object to be mutated (array1) in the iteration callback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Array.fill()`

```js
var array1 = ['S', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'O', 'W'];

array1.fill('X', 3, 10)

console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use array splice() method

```js
var array1= ['S', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'O', 'W'];
// At position 3, delete 7 and add 7 elements: 
array1.splice(3, 7, "X","X","X","X","X","X","X");

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: [].splice is a good way to mutate arrays, good call!

Comment: if you wanted to make this variable you could maybe do something like: `array1.splice(start, end-start, ...Array(end-start).fill("X"));`

Answer (score 1):

One way is with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

This loops through every index of the array, and if the index is between 3 and 9 (inclusive), set it to 'X', otherwise keep it as the original chr (character)

```js
var array1 = ['S', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'O', 'W'];

var array2 = array1.map((chr, idx) => 3 <= idx && idx <= 9 ? 'X' : chr);

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: worksish, but doesn't replace anything, it copies a new array.

Comment: Functional programming is built on the idea that data shouldn't be mutated directly, it should be copied then mutated

Comment: sure, but OP wants to "_replace all the elements at once_", keyword _replace_ (at least to my reading)

Comment: @dandavis okay sure, then OP could just do `array1 = array1.map()`

Comment: @FivePlyPaper: but that doesn't replace anything in the array either, it creates a new one. array1 could have a different name in another part of the program... I agree OP could be clearer though...

Answer (score 0):

It sure does.

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

function replaceWithX(start, end) {
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    arr[i] = 'x'
  }
}

replaceWithX(1, 3)

console.log(arr) // ["a", "x", "x", "x", "e"]
```

Comment: I think the point of this question was to not use a `for` loop since OP said: "Note: I want to perform following operation using array only"

Comment: Didn't see that and thanks for mention it. In that case `array.splice()` is a better choice.